# if width == 200px run function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a [jsFiddle showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/hSqYG/)

I'm not sure why this doesn't work:

```
if ($('#menu').width() == '200px') {
    alert("what");
}
```

I want an alert to appear when the animation is completed. So I assumed that I could say that since when the animation is done the element has a width of 200px, it would show the alert.

Comment: Well, you see, that if statement happens before the animation is done, therefore it will never be true. You should instead add a callback to `.animate` that will run when the animation is complete. `.animate({options},callbackfunction)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the updated fiddle. What I did was added a 'callback' function, which executes whenever the animation is complete.

```
$(this).stop().animate({ width: "200px" }, 250,
  function(){if ($('#menu').width() == '200') { alert("what"); } /* Callback Function */
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

1) You're checking for the value before the animation completes.

2) You width value will be "200" not "200px"

Here is the jQuery documentation. You need to perform your check in the callback section of the code.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.   <---- your value check code goes here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery.width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) returns a number. You are comparing with a string.

Answer (score 1):

`.width()` should return a number, not a "###px" value,  Try `if ($('#menu').width() == 200) {`.